# Fold two array of elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery, optimization

I have two arrays of elements. They have different and unknown lengths.

```
array1 = [$div1, $div2, $div3];  
array2 = [$div4, $div5, $div6, $div7, $div8];
```

I'm looking for the best solution to append them to another element so that they look folded.
The final result should be

```
$div1
$div4
$div2
$div5
$div3
$div6
$div7
$div8
```

I know I could achieve this with some loop and some check on the length, but I was wondering if there was a function to get them folded easily.
I am looking for the most optimized solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming array2 will be always bigger then array1

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3];  
array2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9];  

array3 = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < array2.length ; i++){
  if(i <= array1.length){
     array3.push(array1[i]);
  }
  array3.push(array2[i]);

}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/PGZje/)